# Change SQL AVG and COUNT if a condition is met

Tags: php, sql, count, average

I'm trying to write a Review site. I have most things worked out until I realized I missed one thing. Count Reviews that are listed as Banned against the page Average.

Here is the current SQL that handles the review counting and getting average value.

```
$qa = $db->prepare("SELECT ( AVG(review_service_rating) + AVG(review_price_rating) ) AS average_rating, COUNT(review_service_rating) AS num_service_rating, COUNT(review_price_rating) AS num_price_rating FROM reviews WHERE assigned_id = :review_id ORDER BY review_posted DESC");
$qa->execute(array(':review_id' => $_GET['page_id']));
$ra = $qa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now. I added a DB row called **review_banned** which is a `simple 0 = no or 1 = yes`

How would I add that to my existing SQL query to prevent it from counting reviews that are listed as banned.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to exclude them from both the average and count, or just the average?

Comment: @Barmar I just want to exclude them from the Average as overall Average % is what the User will be looking at. My system does not use amount of reviews someone has, it's all based on there scores.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That will exclude them from the counts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the rating with `0` when `review_banned = 1`.

```
SELECT AVG(IF(review_banned=1, 0, review_service_rating)) + AVG(IF(review_banned=1, 0, review_price_rating)) AS average_rating, ...
```

Comment: Awesome the code works. I however did run into a small problem. Since the reviews aren't being counted the page average is actually growing. How would I go about banned reviews actually counting against the page average and therefor dropping it down?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. It should just be an average of the non-banned reviews, so how are they making the average grow? Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. You start with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, the average is `3`. Then you ban `1`, so the average becomes `3.5`. What do you want the new average to be in that case?

Comment: so when I replace the 0 (default value for review_banned) with 1, then the Average % for that particular page goes up. Technically banned reviews should have there default rating overridden to 0/10

Comment: A banned rating is treated as if it had never been submitted in the first place. So it's like the ratings were `2, 3, 4, 5`, the average is `3.5`. But if you banned the reviewer who rated it `5`, the ratings become `1, 2, 3, 4`, and the rating goes down to `2.5`.

Comment: It goes up or down depending on whether the banned rating was lower or higher than the average.

Comment: Treating a banned review as `0` seems wrong. Why should a banned reviewer be treated as if the product was bad?

Comment: So I currently am pulling 6 reviews for 1 page. The reviews use 2 rows. Pricing 0/5 and Services 0/5 making it xx/10. I then count all this ??/10 add them together and get a % value for the page. So let's say all reviews are 7/10 for 6 reviews on that page we get 70% rating for Company ABC. If I change one of the reviews to banned (1) the system highlights it as Red, but the % remains at 70%

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear it's more like a Fake review, that's treated as a 0, because it's fake, therefor penalizing the company for posting fakes.

Comment: Change `NULL` to `0`.